# Arduino. Read two MQTT topics from arduino and store payload of topics at two diferent variable

Tags: variables, arduino, mqtt

I new in Arduino!
I have two topics on MQTT server, "arduino/temp" and "arduino/humid".
On Arduino, I want to store in a two diferent variable, payload of this topics("arduino/temp" and "arduino/humid")

My code is here:

```
    char myTemp[5];
    char myHum[5];

    void callback(char *topic, byte *payload, unsigned int length) {
    Serial.print("Message arrived in topic: ");
    Serial.println(topic);
//  if(strcmp(topic, "arduino/temp") == 0) {
    if (String(topic) == "arduino/temp") {
    Serial.println(strcmp(topic, "arduino/temp") == 0);
    Serial.print("Message:");
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          Serial.print((char) payload[i]);
          myTemp[i] = (char) payload[i];
      }
      Serial.println();
      Serial.println(myTemp);
      Serial.println("-----------------------");
      }
      else {
      Serial.println(strcmp(topic, "arduino/humid") == 0);
      Serial.print("Message:");
      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          Serial.print((char) payload[i]);
          myHum[i] = (char) payload[i];
      }
      Serial.println();
      Serial.println(myHum);
      Serial.println("-----------------------");
      } 
      }
```

I get correct payload, but i can't asign corectlly to an variablle.
This is the result:

```
    13:08:34.741 -> Message arrived in topic: arduino/temp
    13:08:34.741 -> 1
    13:08:34.741 -> Message: 21.30
    13:08:34.741 ->  21.30
    13:08:34.741 -> -----------------------
    13:08:35.670 -> Message arrived in topic: arduino/humid
    13:08:35.670 -> 1
    13:08:35.670 -> Message: 43.30
    13:08:35.670 ->  43.3021.30
    13:08:35.670 -> -----------------------
```

Can you help me, please?

Comment: add the terminating zero for the C string `myHum[length] = 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix is adding one more char to both and setting its value to `'\0'`. This character you are missing is called the null terminator which will let the `println()` function know that your string has ended.

```
    char myTemp[6];
    char myHum[6];

    void callback(char *topic, byte *payload, unsigned int length) {
    Serial.print("Message arrived in topic: ");
    Serial.println(topic);
    if (String(topic) == "arduino/temp") {
    Serial.println(strcmp(topic, "arduino/temp") == 0);
    Serial.print("Message:");
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          Serial.print((char) payload[i]);
          myTemp[i] = (char) payload[i];
      }
      myTemp[5] = '\0';
      Serial.println();
      Serial.println(myTemp);
      Serial.println("-----------------------");
      }
      else {
      Serial.println(strcmp(topic, "arduino/humid") == 0);
      Serial.print("Message:");
      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          Serial.print((char) payload[i]);
          myHum[i] = (char) payload[i];
      }
      myHum[5] = '\0';
      Serial.println();
      Serial.println(myHum);
      Serial.println("-----------------------");
      } 
      }
```

Note: you can also test by adding the extra char only and not setting the value up as some compilers will set it to 0 by default.